# Converting array to raw binary python. Getting question mark character in file

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

```
convert.astype('float64').tofile(output)
```

Convert is an array set up by numpy with floats in the range of ±1.00e±13.
This should copy the raw binary from convert to the location output. The raw binary gets to the file fine, but there are many �. What is wrong with the code? Example of raw binary is below (The other characters are fine I do not want 0s and 1s.

```
�x1N4?��r1��.�3\C�
```

Could it have to do with 'float64'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because of the character encoding of your text editor, presumably.

Comment: I am using TextWrangler which should be able to encode these charaters.

Comment: If it is binary, then it is probably raw hex data. That will be appear to be any number of random characters, or, if the editor is expecting a particular character set, a bunch of question marks.